# How to implement user certificate based authentication using watir webdriver/headless

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a generic user account for my test automation framework and i need a way  to pass it's .cert when logging in to testing server using watir Webdriver Headless.

Any help is greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Have you checked out http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-certificates?

Comment: @orde :  I  have a trusted cert and thats needs to be selected while logging in to server.